# Enable/disable cell in Excel conditional upon which cell the user enters a value in first

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have three fields in A1, A2 and A3 cells in Excel. All the three fields are unlocked in the first instance.

- If the user enters a value in A3 first, A1 and A2 should be disabled or locked.
- If user enters a value in A1 then A2 should be mandatory, but A3 will be locked or disabled.

In other words the user has to fill A1 and A2, but not A3, or the user should fill A3 but not A1 and A2. Can this be achieved in Excel by using IF and else?

Comment: What you've tried? Where did you get struck?

Comment: I tried conditional formatting  but it did not work, I am trying if and else but i am not getting the desired result may be not writing it properly

Comment: Conditional formatting won't prevent data entry in a cell. How you've tried it and else? From your various comments in a bit confused now on what exactly need to achieve. Please edit your post and clarify it.

Answer (score -1):

**Follow these  steps:**

**Method 1:**

- Select Cells `A1:A2`, or which you only allow to edit.
- **Right click** then from pop up menu click **Format Cells**.
- From **Format Cells dialog**, hit **Protection tab**

[image]

- **Uncheck the Locked box**, & finish with **Ok**.
- Click **Review Tab** then **Protect Sheet.**
- Enter Pass code into the **Protect Sheet dialog box** and hit **Ok**.

[image]

**N.B.** For `A3`, first *Unprotect* Sheet & repeat above shown steps.

---

**Method 2:**

```
Sub LockCells()

Dim mainworkBook As Workbook

Set mainworkBook = ActiveWorkbook

mainworkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2").Value = "Lock"
   mainworkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2").Locked = True
   mainworkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Locked = False
   ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Unlockcells()

  Dim mainworkBook As Workbook

  Set mainworkBook = ActiveWorkbook

  mainworkBook.Sheets("Sheet11").Range("A3").Value = "Free"
    mainworkBook.Sheets("Sheet11").Range("A1:A2").Locked = False
    mainworkBook.Sheets("Sheet11").Range("A3").Locked = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

**N.B.**

- Press **Alt+F11** to open VB editor then *Copy & Paste* these codes as Standard Module.
- **Unprotect** the Sheet before RUN any of the Macros.

*Now changes only be allowed to the unlocked cells.*

Comment: Rajesh , thanks for responding, Probably i did not elaborate my query properly. I have three fields A1, A2 and A3 cells.. all the three fields are unlocked in the first instance. If the user enter value in A3 first , A1, and A2 should be disabled or locked. If user enter value in A1  then A2 should be mandatory but A3 will be locked or disabled.in other words user has to fill A1 and A2 but Not A3, or user should fill A3 but not A1 and A2. Can this be achived by using IF and else , Can you give me syntax for it. thanks in advance.

Comment: @RaghuRags, in that case if you are trying Method 1 then flip the procedure and start with A3 to edit and lock others,, then unlock A1:A2 but lock A3,, and in case of method 2 RUN Unlockcells macro first !!

Comment: Cont.. or you may try need Worksheet Change Event,,, read command line in both Macros are doing same you are suppose to do!!

Comment: Write your concern that why this has been down voted?